# Triggering a gitlab CI pipeline on a successful merge

Tags: gitlab, yaml, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I'm working on a gitlab-ci build script for a project. I have managed to get the script working for manual triggers, but now I want to add some automation. The rules for my build are:

1. When a merge request for one of several specific branch completes successfully, run the pipeline automatically.
2. When a merge request for a branch not matching any of the previous branches completes successfully, create a pipeline but wait for manual input to run.
3. For non-merge events (commits and pushes) do not create a pipeline.

My script so far looks like this:

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  mcUser: "gitlab-runner"
  KEY_NAME: "gitlab-runner"
  VERSION: "0.0.2-SNAPSHOT"
  PROFILE:
    value: "dev"
    options:
      - "dev"
      - "test"
    description: "select a profile to deploy"

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "develop"
      variables:
        PROFILE: "dev"
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "test"
      variables:
        PROFILE: "test"
    - when: never

build-dev:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - development
  script: 
    - echo "build something"
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false

deploy-dev-1:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - development
  needs:
    - job: build-dev
      artifacts: true
  script: 
    - echo "deploying to $HOST"  
  variables:
    NODE1: "99009"
    HOST: "myapp-$PROFILE"

deploy-dev-2:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - development
  needs:
    - job: build-dev
      artifacts: true
  script: 
    - echo "deploying to $HOST"  
  variables:
    NODE1: "99008"
    HOST: "myapp-$PROFILE"
```

If I create a merge request targeting the 'develop' branch, a pipeline is created immediately rather than waiting for the merge to be run. It is also still creating a manual pipeline. How should I modify my script to

A) wait for the merge to complete before creating a pipeline and

B) run the pipeline automatically when the target branch is 'develop' or 'test'?

Comment: I think the problem you have here is that a "merge" is really no different than any other commit/push event on the target branch.